# How does importing types from System.Linq add methods to other classes?

Tags: c#, linq

While working through a tutorial on the entity framework for .net core, I noticed that when looking at the available methods for the DbSet in the code below, after inserting `using System.Linq;` was vastly different than before.

```
        private static void SimpleSamuraiQuery()
        {
            using (var context = new SamuraiContext())
            {
                var samurais = context.Samurais. // Add(), Remove(), etc..
            }
        }
```

After including the using statement, I am suddenly able to see all the Linq methods that you'd expect to see, but it made me a bit curious so I decided to inspect the DbSet class by pressing F12:
`public abstract class DbSet<TEntity> : IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IEnumerable, IQueryable, IAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>, IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>, IListSource where TEntity : class`

I notice that it implements the `System.Linq.IQueryable` interface, but in the DbSet class itself none of the Linq methods are declared. To me this seems a bit strange, but I decide to dig deeper and check out the `IQueryable` interface:

```
namespace System.Linq
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Provides functionality to evaluate queries against a specific data source wherein
    //     the type of the data is known.
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   T:
    //     The type of the data in the data source.
    public interface IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IQueryable
    {
    }
}
```

Wtf? Pardon my french, but what is going on here? Why does writing `using System.Linq` seem to "inject" more methods into a class, and why is the interface seemlingly empty?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: Extentions methods.  You should check out the [`Queryable` class](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs).

Comment: Thanks! I'll check those out

Comment: Since the title of this question is based on a falsehood -- the interface is not empty! -- you might consider re-titling this question.

Comment: You're right, I will retitle this question. Thanks for the answer! Really appreciate it!

Comment: While the new title is better, I actually like the old title better, since it was more searchable.  I think anyone who was stuck on the same thing as Magnar would use terms closer to Magnar's original terms.  See also related math.meta post, [Retitling Questions - a modest proposal](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8765/3862)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is going on here? Why does writing `using System.Linq` seem to "inject" more methods into a class, and why is the interface is seemingly empty?

Those methods are *extension methods*, and they are brought into play by the `using` directive.

You can do this yourself. Make a namespace that contains a static class with accessible static methods whose first formal is marked `this`:

```
namespace Frobber
{
  public interface IBlob 
  {
    int Blob { get; }
  }
  public static class MyExtensions
  {
    public static int AddOne(this IBlob b)
    {
      return b.Blob + 1;
    }
  }
}
... elsewhere ...
using Frobber;
...
IBlob b = whatever();
int x = b.AddOne();
```

All the "LINQ" methods on `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` are actually extension methods. The reasoning behind this feature is: the `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` methods are *the same no matter what the class type is*, so it would be onerous to make those methods part of the contract of `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQuerable<T>`. Instead, you implement them once, and bring them "into play" with a `using` directive.

Extension methods are resolved as follows: if "normal" overload resolution fails to find an applicable member, then we start looking for static classes that are top-level members of "used" namespaces; if those static classes have extension methods of the appropriate name, a second round of overload resolution starts with those methods as candidates. Since `using` directives can happen at different nesting levels, we might end up going to a third round of overload resolution, but in practice this is rare.

> why is the interface is seemingly empty?

The interface is not empty. I don't know how you are looking at the contents of the interface but whatever it is, something is going wrong.

`IQueryable<T>` has members `ElementType`, `Provider` and `Expression`.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=netframework-4.8 for the details.

Comment: I am looking at the definition of the interface by pressing F12 on `IQueryable` in DbSet.cs and I am using Visual Studio Pro 2019. Should I be able to see the contents of this interface? If so, then it is very curious why I'm not able to.